# Lambda coming back up after down time

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-streams

If for some reason aws lambda goes down, how does it behave once it is back up?

Let me explain what I am trying to achieve. I have a stream enabled dynamodb table and a lambda which keeps listening on dynamodb changes. If for some reason lambda goes down and at the same time some changes happen to the data in dynamo db, does that mean those changes are lost and lambda will not know about it? Or once the lambda is up, will it somehow know about the updates?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't think anybody could necessarily answer this because AWS Lambda doesn't go "down", or at least doesn't have operational issues often enough to say that it might go "down" in any particular way. It is a regional based service that would survive problems with an AZ outage. However, if I were to guess at the behaviour, it would probably work off a 'queue' (or more accurately, a 'stream') of changes from DynamoDB so it should continue from where it previously processed a record.

Comment: I have seen Lambda go down once. Significant outage in us-east-1 last year.

Answer (score 1):

Records are retained in the DynamoDB stream for 24 hours. If the Lambda function that is subscribed to the stream fails or fails to be invoked (due to an outage), then it is retried until it succeeds with exponential backoff.

Comment: Docs link, please?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.html